# Will cherry-picking on a tag affect the latter?

Tags: git, git-tag, git-cherry-pick

While doing a release, I checked out the previously released tag and cherry-picked the new items (using `git cherry-pick <commit-id>`) into it. Then, I created a new tag using `git tag <tag-name>`.

Will this  affect the old tag I cherry-picked the changes into?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In one word: no. Tags, once created, [are not meant to move around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849019/move-tag-one-commit-ahead/25849917#25849917) like branch references do. You'd need to deliberately use

```
git tag --force v1.0 <some-other-commit>
```

to move the `v1.0` tag to some other commit. Cherry-picking other commits (in other words, applying the changes introduced by those other commits) on top of a tagged commit won't affect the tag.

As an example, if `v1.0` is a tag and your history looks as follows,

```
A -- B [master,v1.0]
 \
  C -- D [develop]
```

and then you run

```
git checkout v1.0
git checkout -b rc1.1
git cherry-pick C
git cherry-pick D
```

you'll end up with

```
A -- B [master,v1.0]
 \    \
  \    C' -- D' [HEAD,rc1.1]  
   \
    C -- D [develop]
```

The `v1.0` tag will stay in place, still pointing at commit B.

Answer (score 2):

When you cherry-pick a commit, Git is essentially creating a patch from that commit (finding out what kind of changes it introduced) and applies that to the current HEAD. In that process, a completely new commit is created without any link back to the original commit you cherry-picked from. Git will just copy the commit message and commit author and reuse it in the new commit; but apart from that, it’s a completely separate commit.

As such, it’s no different to creating a new commit yourself. So no, cherry-picking, like committing anything, will not affect other commits or tags.