# GIT, how to replicate a moved tag without command from all users?

Tags: git

Someone have moved a tag from a commit to another one.

But everyone else have the tag pointing to the old commit. And if I want to fetch the tag: `git fetch --tags`, I have an error: `! [rejected] tag1 -> tag1  (would clobber existing tag)`.

The only way I found, it's to force the fetch: `git fetch --tags -f`

But, there is a way to avoid a forced fetch from all users ? Something I can do on my PC, push on the remote (can be force) and automatically solve the issue on all users PC without doing anything different than usual. Some users are not developers, and they are not used to doing somme command lines and they usually use graphical software to deal with GIT.

Comment: Moving a tag in git is a [pool of tears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849019/move-tag-one-commit-ahead/25849917) especially if the repository is shared. You should undo the move, by putting the tag back where it was. The procedure is explained in the linked question.

Comment: I know, but someone did and now I have to fix... moving back it's not a good option for me, our tag names have naming convention, and some user already did the fix by there own. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, that just means that you have two population of users: one with the old tag and one with the new. One of the two has to die, you are telling me that you already manage to revert the tag on the largest group? If not, probably is less work to let the population with the new tag die and put back the old tag.